# Минимально необходимые параметры для PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

В [документации NGINX](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param) указано, что минимально необходимые параметры это:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www/scripts/php$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
```

Но экспериментальным путём выяснилось, что такой конфиг работать не будет (к сожалению без вывода ошибки в `/var/log/nginx/error.log` или `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log`, просто статус 200 и пустая страница), т.к. нужно обязательно отправить ещё и `REQUEST_METHOD`, а `QUERY_STRING` наоборот отправлять не обязательно:

```
server {
    location / {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/index.php;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    }
}
```

**Вопрос: Ошибка у меня или в документации?**

Comment: Там приведён пример минимальных параметров. Все зависит от скрипта php, полагаю. Но вот у вас уже второй вопрос на эту тему. Я удивляюсь - сколько часов вы потратили, чтобы сэкономить 1 микросекунду на 1 запрос?

Comment: @KAGGDesign 1. В документации NGINX неправильно указаны минимальные параметры. 2. Я не оптимизирую, а просто учусь - это пример из руководства для начинающих и там такая же ошибка с параметрами. http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html

Comment: Там дословно написано "пример минимальных параметров". Пример.

Comment: Да и неважно все это. Укажите вы 2 или 6 параметров - медленнее не будет.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Да не работает их пример говорю же. Не работает.

Comment: А я написал, что это зависит, наверное, от скрипта php. И если так, то понятно, почему они употребили слово "пример".

Comment: @KAGGDesign Скрипт простой: `<?php echo 'Hello, World!';`.